# Gson annotations not working with my model.

Tags: java, serialization, gson, azure-mobile-services

I am using GSON to convert a Java model to JSON so it can be stored on Windows Azure Mobile. This is the model I created with the annotiations,getters and setters. However its not being stored.
Is there a special naming convention that should be followed when doing this?

```
public class Alarm
{
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
private int alarmId;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("completed")
private Boolean completed;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("time")
private String time;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("days")
private int days;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("alarm_status")
private String alarmStatus;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("alarm_name")
private String alarmName;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("milliseconds")
private int milliseconds;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("filename")
private String filename;
/*
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("requester_id")
private String requesterId;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("requestee_id")
private String requesteeId;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("file_format")
private String fileFormat;

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("date_set")
private String dateSet;




public Alarm()
{

}

/**
 * Getters and setters
 *
 */
public int getAlarmId() {
    return alarmId;
}

public void setAlarmId(int alarmId) {
    this.alarmId = alarmId;
}

public Boolean getCompleted() {
    return completed;
}

public void setCompleted(Boolean completed) {
    this.completed = completed;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public int getDays() {
    return days;
}

public void setDays(int days) {
    this.days = days;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return alarmStatus;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.alarmStatus= status;
}

public String getName() {
    return alarmName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.alarmName = name;
}

public int getMilliseconds() {
    return milliseconds;
}

public void setMilliseconds(int milliseconds) {
    this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
}

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public String getRequesterId() {
    return requesterId;
}

public void setRequesterId(String requesterId) {
    this.requesterId = requesterId;
}

public String getDateSet() {
    return dateSet;
}

public void setDateSet(String dateSet) {
    this.dateSet = dateSet;
}

public String getRequesteeId() {
    return requesteeId;
}

public void setRequesteeId(String requesteeId) {
    this.requesteeId = requesteeId;
}

public String getFileFormat() {
    return fileFormat;
}

public void setFileFormat(String fileFormat) {
    this.fileFormat = fileFormat;
}




@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Alarm && ((Alarm) o).alarmId == alarmId;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the errors persist just simply attached this function to your GSONBuilder.

```
setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
```

So that GSON could automatically generate the names. Once this function is used you can remove the annotations that are present.

Comment: and obfuscate in proguard

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but answering it just in case it helps others:

I faced the same problem.  Looks like "sonar" plugin brought in a Gson implementation that had the bug.  So, make sure you use the google Gson in "com.google.gson" package.  Check your import statements or use FQN:

```
com.google.Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

maven dependency (as of Jan/2019) for google implementation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OSGi/Eclipse make sure all the GSON packages are imported.

I ran into this problem in an OSGi project and it turned out that not all of the GSON packages had been imported into the bundle that was exporting the jar with my model objects (GSON was coming from a separate bundle). This was causing GSON to process the model objects as though there were no annotations on them and not throw any exceptions.